# Trying to show/hide input based on click in checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.enable = function () {
        return this.show().removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    $.fn.disable = function () {
        return this.hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    var incomeType = $("#MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox");
    var incomeTypeStatusSection = $("#incomeTypeStatusDiv, #incomeTypeStatusDiv input, #incomeTypeStatusDiv textarea, #incomeTypeStatusDiv select");
    setControls();

    incomeType.change(function () {
        setControls();
    });

    function setControls() {
        switch (incomeType.val()) {
            case "FullTime":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "PartTime":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "SelfEmployed":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.enable();
                break;
            case "SocialSecurity":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "Retirement":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "ChildSupport":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "Maintenance":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
            case "Other":
                incomeTypeStatusSection.disable();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

The code in my view is simply:

```
<div id="incomeTypeStatusDiv">
   <!--Show some hidden inputs here-->
</div>
```

`MyModel.IncomeTypeCheckBox` is based on an `enum` which corresponds to the `case` values above.

I am able to use the above javascript with a drop down list, for example. The selection will show/hide the appropriate `<div>`.

I am now trying to use that same code to show/hide based on the check box list selection, but without success. The `<div>` I want to hide is showing up and not being hidden. **What am I missing that it won't work with a checkbox list? How do I make this work with a check box list (i.e., if I click "SelfEmployed" check box it will show appropriate `<div>` and when I uncheck "SelfEmployed" checkbox it will hide the `<div>`?**

I could do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='stepincomeinformation.incometypecheckbox']").click(function () {
        var check_value = $(this).val();
        if (check_value == 'selfemployed') {
            $("#incometypecheckbox_selfemployed").toggle(this.checked);
        }
    });
    $("#incometypecheckbox_selfemployed").hide();
    });
```

but then if the `<div>` is hidden, it won't allow me to move on because it's trying to validate. The other javascript doesn't validate the `<div>` if it's hidden.

The javascript is based upon [Validating a dynamic UI with Mvc2](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/07/07/validating-a-dynamic-ui-with-mvc-2.aspx), and has worked well for me. It's used to disable validation when the `<div>` is hidden (and uses a mod to `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` as well as a binder.

Any help is appreciated.

**SEE FINAL RESULT BELOW (Based on Answer)**

Comment: @gdoron Tried to state a more appropriate question. Basically, the javascript I posted is not working to hide the `<div>` based on the checkbox list selection. It's not hiding at all. Also updated post  bit more.

Comment: I suspect there is a more elegant way to do this rather than to hack `MicrsofotMvcValidation.js` but I've not been able to find it. I guess the old addage "if it ain't broke..." would apply.

Comment: are you rendering a checkbox list or just a bunch of individual checkboxes?  i.e. does each checkbox have its own id while sharing the same name with the others, making it a checkbox list, like so?: <input type="checkbox" id="fullTimeIncomeType" name="MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox" value="FullTime" />, <input type="checkbox" id="partTimeIncomeType" name="MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox" value="PartTime" />, etc.

Comment: @jimmym715 Ah, yes, each checkbox has its own id while sharing the same name. If so I guess that's the problem? I will check back tomorrow and report. Thanks.

Comment: well, in a checkbox list, each checkbox should have its own ID while sharing its name with the other checkboxes in the list.  Note though, if you only want one box to be checked, as it appears is your intent, it would be better to use a radio button list, as "select one" is inherent in a radio button list but must be validated in a checkbox list

Comment: @jimmym715 I do want multiple selects for checkbox, however, in the instance where one is checked I want to show a `<div>` specific to what is checked (and vice versa: if unchecked I want `<div>` to be hidden). Out of the choices I expect to replicate the behavior for other check boxes. So, if 2 of 10 are checked, show 2 `<div>`'s and vice versa.

Comment: fair enough... I think I may know the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code you posted, an incomeType variable is set:

```
var incomeType = $("#MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox");
```

At this point, I'm guessing that `MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox` is the name assigned to all of the incomeType checkboxes.

If that's the case, then this likely explains why there are issues.

First, because `MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox` is a name, and not an ID, jQuery can't access the value via `$('#MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox')`

Second, even if jQuery could access what `MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox` would contain in a normal form submission, the rest of the code would only work when a single box is checked, as multiple boxes being checked would result in `MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox` containing a comma-separated string of checkbox values for the selected checkboxes.

So, there are two options here.

The first option is the ugly task of checking each checkbox individually by its ID, but that's not what you want since it's painful and inefficient.

The second option is to change interpretation of the incomeTypes that are checked to something like this:

```
function setControls() {
    $('input:checked[name="MyModel_IncomeTypeCheckBox"]:checked').each(function () {
        var checkedIncomeType = $(this).val();
        handleShowHide(checkedIncomeType);
    });
}

function handleShowHide(incomeType)
{
    // move the switch statement here
}
```

Now I haven't tested this, but it should get you most of the way there, at least.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not good with javascript. I've rearranged my code using your second option and it's not working at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you notice, that last code chunk I listed works to show/hide the `<div>` but I mentioned that it won't validate.  Validation is based on the `disable` and `enable` function in the first code chunk I listed. Is there any way to modify that last chunk to utilize `disable` and/or `enable` (i.e., using those will allow validation to work)?

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you're trying to disable the form elements inside a div with id="incomeTypeStatusDiv".  Is there only one div with this id?  (also, why are you hiding the checkbox?  how would someone uncheck it if it's hidden?)

Comment: The checkbox list always appears. Selections show/hide `<div>`'s. If the `SelfEmployed` check box is checked, then a `<div>` with a unique ID is shown - it has a textbox for an amount. If it's not checked, or if it is unchecked, then that `<div>` is hidden. The default for that `<div>` is hidden. The first block of code with the `switch` statement is tied to a validation binder - the `disable` function triggers it (if its disabled, no validation takes place, i.e., the `<div>` is hidden).

Comment: Somewhat of a new question if you are interested in some points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402793/jquery-logic-working-3-4-of-the-way-check-box-list-how-do-i-make-it-work-100

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. @jimmyym715's answer led me in the right direction. Giving him credit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='MyModel.IncomeTypeCheckBox']").
            click(function () {
        var check_value = $(this).val();
        if (check_value == 'SelfEmployed') {
            $("#IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed, #IncomeTypeCheckBox_
                SelfEmployed input").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed, #IncomeTypeCheckBox
                _SelfEmployed input").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else if (check_value != 'SelfEmployed') {
            $("#IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed, 
                #IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed input").
                    hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
 });
    $("#IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed, 
        #IncomeTypeCheckBox_SelfEmployed input").hide().
            attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Needs a bit of tweaking, but almost there.